# How is "gone" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I'm a native Spanish speaker who's trying to grasp some of the subtleties of (American) English pronunciation. I think the sounds that give me the most trouble are the triplet of low back vowels: /ɑ/, /ʌ/ and /ɔ/. The word "gone" is especially tricky, because each time I hear it I hear something different:

- Sometimes I think it's with a /ɔ/, as if it was "gawn". From my very limited experience, it would seem like this is more common in Southern accents.
- Other times it sounds like a /ɑ/, the same vowel as in "pot".
- The third option would be /ʌ/, like "gun", but I'm pretty sure this is not it.

Which one of these is it? Does it depend on the accent?

Comment: Both *on* and *gone* are pronounced either with /ɔ/ or /ɑ/, depending on the regional dialect. And they don't always rhyme.

Comment: I doubt the usage is so well-known in the US, but many UK speakers reserve a special pronunciation of ***gone*** for facetious contexts like [*"Not lorst, but **gorn** before"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+lorst+but+gorn+before%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is that some sort of ["intrusive r"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110227/2085), or is that just one of your British "fake r" thingies?  Anyway, I always thought that a [gorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorn_(Star_Trek)) was some sort of [Awful Green Thing from Outer Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_Green_Things_From_Outer_Space).

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think it's an "intrusive r" - that's the one in, for example, *loweR or upper*, where I suppose everyone has to enunciate the first R because schwa followed by vowel is awkward. I don't what a British "fake r" is, though. All I can say is lots of dialectal speakers (incl. "Cockneys") will say ***gawn*** quite naturally - but in my experience, ***gorn*** is usually a deliberate affectation (particularly common in that "Muvva's lament" context I linked to, as [popularised on Cream's *"Disraeli Gears"*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX06inW2hK4))

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess what I’m asking is what the IPA is. By "fake r" I mean a silent letter, one spelled but not said. Consider these various possible pronunciations of *gone*: `[gən]`, `[gɑn]`, `[gɒn]`, `[gɔn]`, `[gɔɹn]`, `[goɹn]`, and `[gorn]`. Do you mean one of those, and if so, which one in particular? If you don’t mean one of those, could you please show me what you do mean?

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not too hot on IPA. I mean the rendition of *not lorst but gorn before* at about 1:30 in my Disraeli Gears link above. Incidentally, when I just played it myself a few minutes ago, one of my xmas house guests pointed out that we Brits also have that "extraneous /r/" in certain "plummy, cut-glass" accents *("Waiter! This salmon mousse has gone **orf**!")*. We're not sure, but we think in *that* accent, ***gone*** isn't pronounced ***gorn***.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

English vowels have a large amount of variation between accents and individual speakers. Even among speakers who pronounce *cot* and *caught* differently, *gone* and *on* may be pronounced either way. *Gone* and *on* do not belong to any [lexical set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set), but the closest one for me is *cloth*.

So it’s generally pronounced /gɑn/, and that’s the pronunciation I would prefer if you’re learning American English. But as you have noticed, in some accents it’s /gɔn/ (as in *gaunt*). As Peter Shor says, it *usually* rhymes with *on*.

I think /gʌn/ is possible, but would analyse it as an unrounded version of the /gɔn/ pronunciation, perhaps Scottish or northern English, in which *gun* is likely to be pronounced /gʊn/. And as with any vowel, in unstressed position it can become /ə/. So /gən/ is also possible, albeit unlikely because *gone* is rarely unstressed. For example:

> He’s gone out to the store.
>   [ˌhiz.gən.ˈaʊʔ.tə.ðə.ˈstɔr]

Comment: I thought that in American English, *gone* and *on* didn't fit well into any lexical set.

Comment: @PeterShor: I don’t know, you may be right. No counterexample came to mind is all.

Comment: If you look at the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloth) dictionary, they give *cloth* the symbol ȯ, which means you should pronounce the same way you do *caught* (things in this lexical set are pronounced like *caught* in the U.S. and *cot* in the U.K.) However, they give the pronunciations: \ˈgȯn also ˈgän\ and \ˈȯn, ˈän\.

Comment: The canonical test is the two names _Dawn_ (female: /dɔn/) and _Don_ (male: /dan/) in the U.S.A. People with the merger don't distinguish them in speech. The shift originated during the settlement of the West coast, and the original merger map includes the whole coast, narrowing down to a funnel that terminates around Iowa or so, on the Mississippi. But people move around a lot in the U.S, so it's all over the place.

Comment: ‘Store’ [ˈstəʊr]?! That seems rather peculiar to me. [əʊ] is the diphthong normally cited for BrE (RP) ‘own’ [əʊn], for example. That diphthong certainly doesn’t fit into any pronunciation of ‘store’ that I’ve heard. M-W gives /ȯ/, as in ‘cloth/caught’, though this seems somewhat ill-fitted, too: ‘store’ and ‘caught’ don’t have the same vowel for me. I’d say /stɔr/ and be done with it.

Comment: I’ve edited the pronunciation of *store* but will leave the rest intact. It’s a subtle issue, and while I lack the cot–caught merger, some words do seem to freely vary between those two vowels…this is hard even for native speakers. :P

Comment: @PeterShor Could you please write those in IPA so that I and the rest of the world can understand them?

Comment: @tchrist: I can't write them in IPA; Merriam-Webster uses pronunciation symbols to represent lexical classes. That is, they say that the symbol /ȯ/ should be pronounced like /ɔ/ and /ä/ like /ɑ/ for people who distinguish *caught* and *cot*, and that these two symbols should be pronounced the same for those who merge them. So what *Merriam-Webster* is implying by using these symbols is that even among those people who distinguish between *cot* /kɑt/ and *caught* /kɔt/, *on* and *gone* can be pronounced either with /ɑ/ or /ɔ/. That would be much more complicated to convey with IPA.