# Why "idea-R-of" in Australia

Tags: vowels, australian-english

I am not native english speaker
English is my 2nd Language

When I moved to Australia I noticed people here adding the letter R in between words that ends with vowel and the other that starts with vowel.

Example

When saying **"The idea of"** they say **"The idear of"**

**"The media against ..."** becomes **"The mediar against ..."**

Even when word ends with vowel (speaking vowel) and the next starts with vowel they add R

Example

**"They saw us"** become **"The sawr us"**

Is this common practice in English? or it is just for Australian?
Is there anything similar somewhere else or other rules similar to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Anna(r) and the King" - R liaison in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381552/annar-and-the-king-r-liaison-in-english)

Comment: See also [Non-rhotic dialects and intrusive r](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110227/non-rhotic-dialects-and-intrusive-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the Wikipedia article "[Linking and intrusive R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R)"

Comment: The "intrusive r" occurs in some North American dialects, especially that of Boston, Massachusetts.  President John F Kennedy, who was from Massachusetts, was famous for his "intrusive r" in words like "idea(r)".

Comment: In many non-rhotic dialects (r-dropping) there is a bit of a remnant of the r that pops back in as though it was always there.